# Untrusted SSL disables javascript?

Tags: javascript, ssl

I am working on a Facebook APP and I have a self-signed SSL crt on my website which makes it untrusted (At least I think, Kind of new to the whole SSL thing).

When I am testing the app on localhost or non https connection, the javascript works fine but on https, it doesn't work.

Is there any fix to this?

(Sorry for nooby question)

Comment: So it doesn't work even if you put a single `alert('hello world');` line there?

Comment: Poke around the DOM inspector to see if your JS is even getting loaded correctly?

Comment: Go to your JS console. Chrome tells you in red letters when it blocks requests.

Comment: Make sure that you include all JS (or any external files) using `https` as well